# Apache Wicket : Onclick of a form button, I need to call a small javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, wicket

Onclick of a form button, I need to call a small javascript function. This javascript function should validate some fields in the same form and then call the onSubmit() of the form which is in java.

Main Idea is that let validate happen in client side and not in java.

Complete idea :

I have help.html file as shown below :

```
<form wicket:id="form">
      <input type="text" wicket:id="one"/>
      <input type="text" wicket:id="two"/>
      <input type="submit" wicket:id="save"/>
</form>
```

In help.java, I created a WebMarkupContainer and added this form with this submit button :

```
    container.add(new Button("save") {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
             //saved
        }
    });
```

On click of the button in html, it calls `onSubmit()` and here we can do a validation on the text box values.
But I need to do all the validations in the HTML page itself.

OnClick of the Button Save, it should call a javascript funciton as shown below :

```
    <form wicket:id="form">
          <input type="text" wicket:id="one"/>
          <input type="text" wicket:id="two"/>
          <input type="submit" wicket:id="save" onclick="validateRange()"/>
    </form>
```

JavaScript :

```
    function validateRange(){
          //logic
          //Submit the form
    }
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5):

You need an `AjaxSubmitLink` or something like this. The you need to create a new `IAjaxCallListener`

```
public class MyAjaxCallListener implements IAjaxCallListener{

@Override
public CharSequence getBeforeHandler(Component component) {
    return YOUR_JAVA_SCRIPT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getBeforeSendHandler(Component component) {
    return YOUR_JAVA_SCRIPT;
}

// ...     not needed overrides can return null

}
```

Then in your AjaxSubmitLink you can add this AjaxCallListener

```
   @Override
   protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
      super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
      attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new MyAjaxCallListener());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example [Try if yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/5TMBJ/7/)

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="#">
    <input id="text" type="text"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="TEST"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validate() {
    var value = document.getElementById("text").value;
    if (value == "") {
        alert("you have to write something");
        return false;
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```